# Prevent printing key indexes while printing the value - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hi I have an array like this:

```
array(
  'Home' => array(
    'About',
    'Contact'
  ),
  'News'
);
```

I wrote this to printing them:

```
function show($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
      echo "\n<ul>\n<li>\n" . $key;
      if( ! empty($value)){
        if(is_array($value)){
          show($value);
        }else{
          echo $value;
        }
      }
      echo "\n</li>\n</ul>\n";
    }
}
```

My problem is when I try to `echo $value` It'll print something like this:

```
Home
  0About
  1Contact
0News
```

I tried to `echo $key` where the `echo $value` is here now and I understood it's the key index which is gonna write before the News field or any field that is not an array. I fixed it with turning the single fields to this:

```
array(
  'Home' => array(
    'About' => **array()**,
    'Contact' => **array()**
  ),
  'News' => **array()**
);
```

But I don't want to define additional empty arrays!

Peace Out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function show($arr){
     foreach($arr as $key => $value){
       echo "\n<ul>\n<li>"; 
       if( ! empty($value)){
         if(is_array($value)){
          echo '\n'.$key;
           show($value);
         }else{
           echo $value;
         }
       }
       echo "\n</li>\n</ul>\n";
     } }
```

I would say you have to change the place of you echo (of the $key). If it's not an array, you don't care about the key, right ?

Comment: I tried it but It'll make every thing to step back one field!; I mean It'll be like this e. g. 'AboutMe' and next line 'Us'

Comment: try again, i changed something, forgot about the html

Comment: Thanks It worked. I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes as the Stack is saying :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function show($arr){
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  if (is_numeric($key))
  echo "\n<ul>\n<li>\n";
  else
  echo "\n<ul>\n<li>\n" . $key;
  if( ! empty($value)){
    if(is_array($value)){
      show($value);
    }else{
      echo $value;
    }
  }
  echo "\n</li>\n</ul>\n";
}
}
```

I guess is_numeric should solve your problem.

Comment: If I had fields which they'll start with numbers then what?

Comment: If I understood properly, you want to print key if it is string and don't want numeric keys to be displayed with value. correct me if I am wrong.